# What is the function of "millis()" in this code snippet?

Tags: arduino-uno, ethercard

What is the function of `millis()` in this code snippet?

```
if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/demo/"), "aphorisms.php", website, response_callback);
}
```

Comment: Before you post a question here, you are supposed to do some research yourself. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis

Answer (score 0):

The "timer" variable bumps the current cumulative time, as measured by millis(), and sets a value of 5 seconds greater.  This snippet will reside in a larger loop, and whenever the time since the last iteration exceeds 5 seconds, will execute the subsequent statement and bump the timer again. Else, the snippet simply passes thru.
If you wanted to do something every 5 seconds, or whatever interval you choose, this is a simple way to do that.  Of course, that interval may be elongated, depending on other code in the loop.